# 'Fist of legend' nuances

Tags: usage

For a long time I wanted to ask whether there is any difference between '*Fist of legend*' and '*Legendary Fist*', the first being the name of "Jing wu ying xiong" (original title) starring Jet Li.

The movie is 2 decades old but it is still vivid, I wonder why the translators chose 'of' approach, really why? And do these twos represent one thing or there are some nuances.

Also, is above situation the same as:

'*Heart of (a) lion*' vs '*Lion/lionesque heart*'?

And to go deeper, can we coin '*Legendfist*' after the "*Richard the **Lionheart***" taking into account 'Ironfist' movie (a.k.a. 'Under the Gun') too?

This 'of' constructions did hit me in Zarathustra's book as well: "***pure of eye***, and no loathing lurking", in-here going farther as a variant of **eye of pureness/purity**.

**Add-on:**

I did my own investigation just to get more confused.
The reason, putting in the mix one more movie translated as *Legend of the Fist*!!! **How this wording fits in the whole picture, NO IDEA!**

[image]
[image]
[image]

First off, the sequel spans 38 years from 1972 to 2010.

Probably translators followed the pattern of 1972's *Fist of Fury*, *Fist of Legend* being a remake (1994).
Both movies have the first two kanjis identical - 精武門 vs 精武英雄

- The first two kanjis are 'Jing Wu' which is the name of the famous Chinese martial arts school.
- The third kanji in *Fist of Fury* is 'GATE' thus 'Jing Wu Gate'.
- The third and fourth kanjis in *Fist of Legend* are 'Fine&Military' meaning 'HERO' thus 'Jing Wu Hero', by the way Jet Li's movie 'Hero' has the same two kanjis 英雄.

Three beloved actors did these three movies (in chronological order): Bruce Lee, Jet Li, Donnie Yen.
Another remake was released in 2010 as *Legend of the Fist* a.k.a. 'The Return of Chen Zhen'.

Again translators threw dust in my eyes, the original name is 精武風雲 factored to:

- The first two kanjis are 'Jing Wu', again.
- The third and fourth kanjis in *Legend of the Fist* are 'WIND&CLOUD' thus 'Jing Wu Storm', because AFAK Chinese denote 'storm' as 'wind&cloud'.

Hope someone will shed light on GATE-HERO-STORM triad and where the LEGEND came from.

Comment: As a learner, you should probably *always* avoid coining neologisms like this. You may be *understood* (or perhaps not), but you're unlikely to improve your grasp of English using this approach.

Comment: @FumbleFingers By this approach you mean concatenating words as in *legendfist*, yes? But many times compound nouns are good candidates for such fusion, at least in my eyes, that way the single word comes into its own, quite as *deadeye*, *oldboy*, *ironfist*. As for the marginal coinages, yes, I noticed how a bunch of some native English teachers disliked them. Recently I faced the lack of 'god' adverb counterpart for *devil**ISHLY** fast*, my goal was to stress how divine/harmonious approach trumps a particular ultrafast demonic one. How to feint this problem in your view without coining?

Comment: Use more *existing* words. Even native speakers can't reliably predict how any given neologism will be received. By which I mean not only that people may not *understand* whatever precise sense you want to convey - they may also come to undesirable conclusions about your ability to communicate effectively in English (regardless of whether they understand you correctly or not). As a rule, neologisms are best left to (competent) native speakers.

Comment: ...I for example haven't the faintest idea what your examples *deadeye, oldboy* are supposed to convey.

Comment: Okay, I see now, you suggest that unexperienced users like me pollute English, well I agree partially. I guess this is inevitable when one has beforehand (in one's own language) the counterparts but cannot see them 'COINED' in English, makes sense, yes?

Comment: I don't say you "pollute" English - for all I know in any given context I might find one of your neologisms witty, charming, or otherwise apt. But bear in mind that movie titles are often not really "English" as such anyway. I've actually watched *Oldboy* (not that I think much of it), but I don't know why it's called that. Probably because the juxtaposition of those two words works in Japanese, but it doesn't do anything for me as a native speaker. (Then again, Japan might well be the primary target audience anyway. :)

Comment: Yes, I think this is so, sequences of kanjis usually are not translatable on kanji-per-word premise, they form one word as in the 'Wind-and-Cloud' equals 'Storm' example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This autumn while reading '*Medals and Decorations of Hitler's Germany*' I found one triple/triad word 'totenkopfring', it is a good example how three nouns are merged nicely in 'deathheadring', to me "Death's Head Ring" fails to convey the original, since it may be "parsed" as 'Head Ring of the Death', what do you think? Also one of my favorite books is '*Das Totenschiff*' translated as '*The Death Ship*', nah-nah, how come that Amazon sells a new book (2014) **Deathship** [Kindle Edition] by Steven Oaks? My point, all these restrictive 'rules' out there are ... optional.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about language translation and entertainment title determination, not about learning English.

Comment: @user3169 Just one question: Don't you have something useful in your to-do list but to close people's attempts to learn?
The path of associative thinking is not straight, when one plunges into exploring the 'side effects' it appears as sidetracking, here you simply fail to see that.
But I see here the crowd united, while no real conversations took place. Guys, you are not even off-topic you are off-interacting.

Comment: @Georgi - If you feel like the question should not have been closed, please address that issue _constructively_ by asking a question in meta, not by insulting the community and engaging in name-calling. As for your question here, one can say NOUN OF NOUN, or say ADJ NOUN, and they pretty much mean the same thing (_Furious Fist_ vs _Fist of Fury_, _Pure Eye_ vs _Eye of Purity_, etc.). That much is an English question, but why a movie producer may choose one over the other for a film title is not really on-topic here; perhaps you could ask that on [movies.se].

Comment: @Georgi: What I think is ELL is not the right site to discuss how *anyone*, particularly non-native speakers, might react to some short sequence of familiar evocative terms that *in combination* (possibly "ungrammatically") have no obvious literal sense or established idiomatic sense. To repeat and amplify - even native speakers making movies don't "know" such things. That's why they do market research to find out which titles "work". Which is almost meaningless anyway, since all they care about is *"Which title would make you more likely to buy/watch the movie?"*.

Comment: @J.R. No man, I lost interest you can close it or whatever. To me, asking for help shouldn't be burdened with such restrictiveness like treating the OP as a nagger. My style is to put on the table all aspects (arising along the way) of the primary matter that captivated my attention and see how these distant "off-topic" aspects interrelate. Sadly, I observe how most people get instantly irritated by such fuzzy approaches, they dislike nested question-answer form. In 'I, robot' movie similar instance caught my attention - "thing of beauty", prepositional usage, in general, interest me a lot.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now I see that is the case, both ELU and ELL have their frames, I just don't fit in-there and in-here, so I won't participate anymore, no bad feelings just a disappointment of how my interacting style appears too weird to the majority.

Comment: Well, I hope you can see it's not so much a matter of your "interacting style" seeming "weird" - it's more that the specific issues raised in your question aren't suitable for a ***Q&A*** site like this. There probably aren't any "answers", such as would suit the ELU model. But you might find a forum or discussion board where people could kick ideas around. And if you ever want to explore actual English usage (as opposed to translations, global marketing, or international linguistic crossovers), you know where to find us! :)

Answer (score -1):

In these titles *of* serves to emphasize.

Comment: You mean *Fist of Fury* sounds stronger than *Furious Fist*, is it so? My personal translation (following the pattern of official names) is *Fist of Storm* speaking of *Legend of the Fist*. But my personal preference leans to the new coinage - **Stormfist**. Anyway, I hear for the first time of such strengthifier.

Comment: Aha, well I was referring to the word "of" not your preference but I see why you would think so. [Replace "strengthifier" with "enhancer". It's not a real word.]

Comment: It serves to emphasize what exactly? Would you elaborate?

Comment: It really confuses me how easily some words are targeted as garbage, we have 'strengthify' similarly to 'purify', why you discard it when we have 'purifier'? How to derive the noun out of 'strengthen(s)' - the transitive verb?!

Comment: Never mind, just found 'strengthenER' is in official usage, yet, my question remains, why 'strengthifier' is not a real word? We have 'amplify/amplifier', who decides what is good and what not, patterns are all there just the choice is left to the users/choosers, no?

Comment: Words conjugated and ending in "-ier" usually end in "y", are nouns or are comparative adjectives.

Comment: @TejanaLionel - Rather than elaborating down here in the comments, you really should bolster your answer with an edit instead.